# How to extract ROI from Segmented image with kmeans

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing, k-means, image-segmentation

I applied kmeans Matlab function (5 clusters) on gray level image. My issue is how to get the region of interest? 
I mean how to define resulted imf from using Matlab source code below (which index should I select)?

```
function imf=selectRoi(I)
 c=5;
 H = fspecial('gaussian');
 I = double(imfilter(I,H,'replicate'));
 I=double(I);
 IN=reshape(I, [], 1);
 [iDX nn]   = kmeans(IN,5);                    
 imIDX=reshape(iDX, size(I));
 imf=imIDX==4;
 figure;
 subplot(241); imshow(I); title('Original'); 
 subplot(243); imshow(imIDX==1, []);title(['Kmeans',' : ',num2str(1)]);
 subplot(244); imshow(imIDX==2, []);title(['Kmeans',' : ',num2str(2)]);
 subplot(245); imshow(imIDX==3, []);title(['Kmeans',' : ',num2str(3)]);
 subplot(246); imshow(imIDX==4, []);title(['Kmeans',' : ',num2str(4)]);
 subplot(247); imshow(imIDX==5, []);title(['Kmeans',' : ',num2str(5)]);
end.
```